# Crossing Schengen borders six times during a vacation with different intentions. How to proceed with visas?

Tags: schengen, borders, russian-citizens

Citizen of Russian Federation, permanent resident of the USA needs to travel through Schengen 3 times in a short time span (3 weeks), each time with a different purpose. is traveling on the following itinerary.

1. USA -> Denmark -> Finland (flight) immediate transfer to a train to Russia. Purpose: Transit. Total presence in Schengen 1 long day.
2. Departing to Schengen for a self guided tour of Europe:
   Russia -> Finland -> Stockholm -> Copenhagen -> Somewhere north Germany -> Belgium -> France -> Germany, then Germany - Poland - Belarus - Russia by train. Total duration about 8 days. Out of those 8, about 3 days are in France, 3 days are in Germany. You can assume main destination is Germany.
3. Then: Russia -> Finland (train); Finland -> Denmark -> USA (air). Purpose: Transit. Total time in Schengen zone 2 days.

Questions:

1. Can the said individual obtain single multi-entry visa from a single  country for the entire itinerary? Is it advisable to do so, or is it advisable to obtain separate visa for 1 and 3 and another one for 2.
2. If it is possible, what country should he apply to? The choices seem to be limited to Denmark (first entry) or by the time spent: Finland (3 incomplete days - in transit), Germany (about 3 days, main destination)?

The question is different from another question linked in the following respect: It is asking about the possibility doing two close-spaced journeys with different purpose on the same multi-entry visa from the same country.

Comment: First question is "Can the itinerary be accomplished on a single visa from a single country?" thus not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: All visits to the zone are accomplished by a single visa from a single country. Did you mean single-entry?

Comment: @GayotFow, I meant single multi-entrance visa, issued by a single country.

Clarify please: "visits to the zone are accomplished by". Did you mean "accomplishable by" or "generally accomplished by"? If the former, then which country does the above mentioned person apply to and why? If the latter, then this is not the proper answer to this particular circumstances

Comment: To all downvoters, and those submitting request to close. Can I have a simple plain answer, please? Denmark or Germany/France?

Comment: If you get a multi entry visa then yes, you can do it, there's no limit on how often can you enter the Schengen area with that. (90/180 applies of course)

Comment: All visits into the zone are accomplished by a single visa which is valid for all member states, you cannot have two visas open at a time. Please examine the linked duplicate for answers about which country should process your visa. Thanks

Comment: @chx that I understand. The question is what country?

Comment: @GayotFow, can you provide a link to the rule about no 2 concurrent visas?

Comment: I don't have a reopen vote, but I think this should be reopened. The alleged duplicate does not deal with multiple Schengen zone entries.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the OP clarified that it's a multiple-entry visa. Thanks

Comment: @mzu please amend your question to explain why a multiple-entry visa does not work for you, it's very unclear what you are after, thanks

Comment: @mzu in all events "A holder of a multiple-entry visa may apply for a new visa before the expiry of the validity of
the visa currently held. However, the validity of the new visa must complement the current
visa, i.e. a person cannot hold two uniform visas valid for the same period in time"... is the regulation, hope that helps. Legal basis: Visa Code, Article 9(1)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I will reopen with my hammer if, after reading the question/comments, you feel that it is justified, just shout.

Comment: @GayotFow Should this be treated as one trip or three? For example, suppose the tourism phase did have a primary objective. Should the OP apply to that country? Or should the OP apply to the country of first entry, because there is no other primary country for the first entry-exit pair?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It is a single visit all covered by an MEV. The OP should apply to the German consulate based on what has been provided.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Made question much clearer, sorry for the confusion. Please, vote reopen.

Comment: @GayotFow. The question was edited for clarity. Please, vote reopen